# How to measure the height of a child and pass it to a parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I want to calculate the height of a component and send it to its parent when the page is loaded and resized.

I'm using the below reusable Hook to successfully measure the height of the div inside the header component. But how do I send the `height` calculated from `useDimensions` in the child to its parent component as `headHeight`?

**Measuring Hook**

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

function getDimensionObject(node) {
  const rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    width: rect.width,
    height: rect.height,
    top: 'x' in rect ? rect.x : rect.top,
    left: 'y' in rect ? rect.y : rect.left,
    x: 'x' in rect ? rect.x : rect.left,
    y: 'y' in rect ? rect.y : rect.top,
    right: rect.right,
    bottom: rect.bottom
  };
}

export function useDimensions(data = null, liveMeasure = true) {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({});
  const [node, setNode] = useState(null);

  const ref = useCallback(node => {
    setNode(node);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (node) {
      const measure = () =>
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() =>
          setDimensions(getDimensionObject(node))
        );
      measure();

      if (liveMeasure) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', measure);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', measure);

        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('resize', measure);
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', measure);
        };
      }
    }
  }, [node, data]);

  return [ref, dimensions, node];
}
```

**Parent**

```
export default function Main(props: { notifications: Notification[] }) {
    const { notifications } = props;
    const [headHeight, setHeadHeight] = useState(0)

    const updateHeadHeight = () => {
        setHeadHeight(headHeight)
    }

    return (
         <main>
            <Header updateParent={updateHeadHeight}/>
           {headHeight}
        </main>
    )
}
```

**Child**

```
import { useDimensions } from '../../lib/design/measure';
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

export default function DefaultHeader(props, data) {
    const [
        ref,
        { height, width, top, left, x, y, right, bottom }
      ] = useDimensions(data);
    ;

    return <>
       <div ref={ref} className="header">
          <h1>Hello!</h1>
       </div>   
    </>
}
```

Comment: You can make use of a useRef and forwardRef to fetch the value from a child component and then make use of useEffect to cause a rerender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would call the hook in the `Main` component and wrap the child component in a `forwardRef` ([check docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)).

See full example here:

`Main.tsx`

```
export default function Main(props: { notifications: Notification[] }) {
    const { notifications } = props;
    const [ref, dimensions] = useDimensions()

    return (
         <main>
            <Header ref={ref}/>
           {JSON.stringify(dimensions)}
        </main>
    )
}
```

What's done here, we just pass the ref down the tree to the child component and we just show the dimensions (testing purposes).

`DefaultHeader.tsx`

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const DefaultHeader = forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} className="header" >
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
});

export default DefaultHeader;
```

Here, we just attach the ref to the container that it has previously been (your example).

See full example on [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lake-h7d9ev).

Let me know if you need more explanations on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a useEffect hook within the DefaultHeader component like this:

```js
useEffect(() => props.updateParent(height), [props.updateParent, height])
```

This hook should run anytime it detects changes to the height variable or props.updateParent props. Just make sure you are declaring this hook after the `useDimensions` hook so it doesn't throw an undefined error.

Comment: If he needs the height  of the child only in the parent, it should be better not to duplicate the state, and just pass down from Parent the setState to the custom hook.

Comment: This is correct @CesarePolonara, but I am trying to not alter his code beyond just answering his question to avoid increasing the answer's scope.

But yes, ideally, you want to raise state the dimensions state up to the parent. Tom, see the React Docs on this for more: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @sgarcia.dev Could you show me how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are seriously overcomplicating this by limiting yourself to *the react way* of doing things. You can simply use [Event Bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/6036546) to achieve what you want. All you need to do is dispatch a [Custom Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) event on the child element that will bubble up through each ancestor to the window. Then intercept this event in the parent element and **react** to it.

```js
let m = document.querySelector('main');
let s = document.querySelector('section');
let b = document.querySelector('button');

b.addEventListener('click', event => {
  s.style.height = '200px';
});

m.addEventListener('resize', event => {
  console.log('new size:', event.detail);
});

new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let e of entries) {
    s.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('resize', {
        detail: e.contentRect,
        bubbles: true
      })
    );
  }
}).observe(s);
```

```css
main { background: green; padding: 1rem; margin-top: 1rem; }
section { background: orange; }
```

```html
<button> Test </button>

<main>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

Just implement the [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) block in the child component and the `resize` Event Listener in the parent component.

This method achieves the desired effect in a decoupled and standards-compliant way. The child element is merely announcing the change to it's state (in the DOM, not React state). Any ancestor element can then act on this behavior as needed or ignore it. The parent element can also receive this resize event from any descendant element regardless of how deeply nested it may be. It also does not care which descendant element has changed. If you have multiple descendants that could change, this will trigger for any one of them.

Additionally, the resize event here is **NOT** tied to the window. **ANY** changes to the child element's size will trigger the event listener on the parent.